# Young adult novel: girl from a tribe of warrior women in the Amazon falls in love

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I read this book back in 2004 and it's about a girl, I think her name was "Rain" and she was the best horseback rider/warrior in a tribe of women from the Amazon. Her mother was raped by something like 100 men, so she was never accepted by her mother.

So the society is of all women who only use men for reproduction. I think "Rain" fell in love with a man named "Michael." I think the title was just one word, or "The" something. It had a dark cover, with some blue on it, and I think the girl's face on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The Foretelling* by Alice Hoffman, first published in 2005.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22892.The_Foretelling):

> A coming-of-age story that pierces the soul and heals the spirit, this is the tale of the future leader of the Amazon women warriors. Rain must hold fast to her inner warrior, but she is startled and mystified by the first stirrings of mercy towards the enemy.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!